# Tkinter program into exe

Tags: tkinter, exe, python-3.4

I've probably been completely oblivious to the answer but I want to turn a Tkinter program into an exe file and all the programs I've found that do so either don't work for Python 3.4 or I can't install properly and I don't know why. Can I have some help please?

Comment: What does "can't install properly" mean? Do you get errors? Does your computer crash? ...

Comment: I get an error that basically says Python 3.4 doesn't exist even though I've been using it for about a week on the computer in question, Is it an error with the program cx-freeze or is it a problem with the version of Python I am using, which was a bug fix update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was being a derp after all and just downloaded the wrong version of the program I was trying to use which was cx_freeze.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Py2exe to convert your tkinter to executable file, there is tutorial over [here](http://logix4u.net/component/content/article/27-tutorials/44-how-to-create-windows-executable-exe-from-python-script) to create windows executable from python include tkinter.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I can't find a version of py2exe that works for Python 3.4 are there any others?

Comment: There's software called [cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net) that support Python 3.4 :D I hope it help.

Comment: cx-freeze was the one I found that worked for 3.4 but it didn't install properly because it thought Python didn't exist.

Comment: At the moment only `py2exe` and `cx-freeze` that exists, based on my experiences `cx-freeze` is the one that good. You should try re-install python3 again and install `cx-freeze` inside virtualenv.